# Using Java, How can I find the prime number that is the next smallest to a given integer?

Tags: java, methods

I am confused on a coding project. I am supposed to return the smallest prime number bigger than the `integer "num",` for example `smallestPrimeBiggerThan(20)` should return `23` I already have the code to determine if the number is prime, but I am not sure how to do the rest of the code. I already looked onto this site, however the rest of the explanations are for C and C++. I am not sure how to translate the code between C to Java. Also, I would prefer if this were to be a simple way of completing it, as I am new to code and do not know much about the more complex parts (Arrays and the like).

Here is an example for the arguments

Integer n is 80, so the smallest prime number next to the integer is 83, so the method would return 83

Here is a baseline for the code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(smallestPrimeBiggerThan());

}

public static int smallestPrimeBiggerThan(int num) {

}
```

Comment: `while(!isPrime(num)) { num++; } return num;`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch say one were to pass `23` as input your code would return `23` whereas OP is _supposed to return the smallest prime number bigger than the integer "num"_ which should be `29`

Comment: this fixes it : `while(!isPrime(num)) { ++num; } return num;` (++num will add 1 to num before checking if it is prime)

Comment: @Elliott I think you meant `while(!isPrime(num++));`

Comment: would be more clear to do `for(;!isPrime(num);++num);`

Comment: `public static int smallestPrimeBiggerThan(int num) {
        num++;
        while(!isPrime(num) ) { num++; } return num;
    }`

Comment: @cricket_007 `while(!isPrime(++num)); return num;`

Comment: The whole idea of an `isPrime()` method is wrong. You will be repeating the same calculations over and over again. Incredibly inefficient. Instead you should be *generating* primes, via the sieve, up to the maximum value dictated by your input number, and returning the last.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a snippet I put together (Note: Logic courtesy of @Paul Lemarchand and @Elliot Frisch) along with [this](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-determine-a-prime-number-in-java/) prime algorithm:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter a whole number to find the next highest prime of: ");
    System.out.println(smallestPrimeBiggerThan(input.nextInt()));

}

static boolean isPrime(int n) {
    if (n%2==0) return false;
    for(int i=3;i*i<=n;i+=2) {
        if(n%i==0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public static int smallestPrimeBiggerThan(int num) {
        while (!isPrime(num)) {
            ++num;
        }
        return num;
}
```

I know you already have your prime algorithm, but I wanted it to be able to run off of a copy/paste so I included on from the internet. The part you were looking for is the `while` loop. Every time it loops around it checks if `num` is a prime, but incrementing the variable first so we don't just return on a prime input. If it's not a prime, increment...rinse and repeat until we have a prime then return.

Answer (score 1):

If you not care the precision,you can use the `nextProbablePrime` method of `BigInteger` class.For example:

```
BigInteger index=new BigInteger("20");
System.out.println(index.nextProbablePrime());
```

The `nextProbablePrime` is find a probable prime number.The javadoc:

> Returns the first integer greater than this `BigInteger` that
>        is probably prime.  The probability that the number returned by this
>        method is composite does not exceed 2<sup>-100</sup>. This method will
>        never skip over a prime when searching: if it returns `p`, there
>        is no prime `q` such that `this < q < p`.